# At which part of the code non-static variables are loaded into memory?

Tags: java

```
public class SampleClass 
{
    int a = 10;     //  loaded into memory for every object creation
    int b = 11;     //  loaded into memory for every object creation
    ExtraClass extraClass = new ExtraClass();     //  loaded into memory for every object creation
    static int c;   //  loaded when class is loaded into memory 

    {
        //  IIB
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);  
        System.out.println(extraClass);         
    }

    public SampleClass() 
    {
        super();
        //  call to IIB
        System.out.println("===============");
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(extraClass);             
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
    }
}

class ExtraClass
{

}
```

I know that both `a` and `b` are loaded only when object is created to `SampleClass`. But I was checking at which part of my code they are loaded into memory? I didn't get any conclusion from my output.

```
10
11
com.stack.ExtraClass@19821f
===============
10
11
com.stack.ExtraClass@19821f
```

Comment: Applicable [part of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance initializers (the `{...}` bit) are inlined into constructors, in between `super()` (or `this()`, if that were used instead) and the rest of the constructor's body.

Also member variable initializers (e.g. `int b = 11`) are equivalent to an instance initializer:

```
int b;
{
  b = 11;
}
```

So they are inlined into the constructor too, at the same place. If you've got multiple instance initializer blocks, they are inlined (and hence executed) in the order they appear.

So, your class equivalently looks like the following. Follow that through, and hopefully you should understand the output:

```
public class SampleClass 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    ExtraClass extraClass;
    static int c;

    public SampleClass() 
    {
        super();

        // Variable initializers.
        this.a = 10;
        this.b = 11;
        this.extraClass = new ExtraClass();

        // Explicit instance initializer.
        {
          //  IIB
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);  
          System.out.println(extraClass);         
        }

        //  call to IIB
        System.out.println("===============");
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(extraClass);             
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: so you're saying that the non-static variables are loaded when execution reaches inside the Instance Initialization Block

Comment: I'm saying that initializer blocks are inlined into the constructor. Try decompiling your class with `javap`, you'll see this.